# PhoneGap 2.3 Blackberry10: "Origin local:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10, cordova-2.0.0

I'm trying to run on Blackberry 10 an application which already works fine on Android&iOS.

When I do a call to server I always get "**Origin local:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin**": why I'm facing a cross domain issue"? I never got any issue about cross-domain the other phonegap platforms.

I'm using Cordova 2.3, the latest WebWorks SDk for BB10 and the latest BB10 simulator (but I have the same problem also when deploying on the Dev Alpha B device).

In the config.xml of the project I already checked the :
`<access subdomains="true" src="*"/>`

There is some other configuration around?

Comment: Did you ever find out the issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but I think the issue is that you cannot use a wildcard in the SRC attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax should be `<access subdomains="true" uri="*"/>`

Answer (score -1):

Your hosted service should support cross domain access.

For WCF service the following configurations should be available in the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

<webHttpBinding>
   <binding crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
     <security mode="None" />
   </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

Hope it helps...

Happy Coding!!!